# Returning specific values with Jquery-Ajax request

Tags: c#, ajax, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I am working on a webform with knockout.js. At one point, I get a value based on the selected value in a `select` list. I have the following code within the viewModel:

```
        self.discoveryForms = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.selectedTemplate = ko.observable();
        self.selectedDiscoveryForm = ko.observable();

        //behaviors
        self.selectedTemplate.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            console.log(newValue.DiscoveryFormID());

            self.GetDiscoveryForms(newValue.DiscoveryFormID());
        });

        self.GetDiscoveryForms = function (discoveryFormID) {
            console.log(discoveryFormID);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{ID: '" + discoveryFormID + "'}",
                url: ("Default.aspx/GetDiscoveryForms"),
                dataType: "json",                    
                success: function (response) { self.FindDiscoveryForms(response), console.log(response)}
                });
        }

        self.FindDiscoveryForms = function (response) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(response.d, null, viewModel.discoveryForms);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
```

The c# that gets the data from the entity is this:

```
    [WebMethod]
public static List<DiscoveryForm> GetDiscoveryForms(){
    List<DiscoveryForm> discoveryForms = new List<DiscoveryForm>();

    using (IntranetContainer db = new IntranetContainer())
    {
        discoveryForms = db.DiscoveryForms.Select(x => new DiscoveryForm()
        {
            ID = x.ID,
            Name = x.Name,
            Welcome = x.Welcome,
            WelcomeNote = x.WelcomeNote,
            WelcomeBack = x.WelcomeBack,
            WelcomeBackNote = x.WelcomeBackNote
        }).ToList();
    }

    return discoveryForms;
}

public class DiscoveryForm
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Welcome { get; set; }
    public string WelcomeNote { get; set; }
    public string WelcomeBack { get; set; }
    public string WelcomeBackNote { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that while I want the ajax request to only return discovery forms with `ID` selected by the `selectedTemplate`, it presently returns all of the values into the array. I thought that `data: "{ID: '" + discoveryFormID + "'}",` would do that. Can someone explain to me why this is and how to fix it? Should I be doing something on the c# side? I'm new to javascript, ajax, and knockout.js.

To correct the problem, the query had to look like:

```
   data: "{'id':"+discoveryFormID + "}",
```

and the c# method was changed according to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service must look like

```
public static List<DiscoveryForm> GetDiscoveryForms(int[] ids){
```

And this parameter then must be used for the query.

Right now you don't have anything to narrow your set.

Comment: Cool. I suspected that it was something along those lines. I'm still tweaking it, but that seems to be getting me in a better direction.